# PHP Variable as href in HTML

Tags: php, html, variables, href

I need to open links using PHP variables.

I tried to search for solutions online but no solutions can solve my problem.

Here's my code. When I clicked on the link, nothing happens.

p/s:The link is outside of the localhost.

```
echo '<tr><td colspan ="3"><a href="'.$webPath.'"target="_blank">'.$webPath.'</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: what is `$webPath` holding?

Comment: can you explain what is holding? I am new to php coding

Comment: let me reword my question, what is the variable `$webPath` storing? Cause when I set `$webPath = 'http://www.google.com';` and click on the link it works.

Comment: it's a link that points to my file in windows. I need to open this file in the browser.

Comment: the error is something to do with your variable `$webPath` maybe its going to a file that doesn't exist or an incorrect path?

Comment: the file exists. I can copy the link and paste manually in the address bar to load it.

Comment: Does the variable start with a `/` ? to specify it to start at the root folder.

Comment: the variable includes the full path of the file. Technically, it includes all the root folders.

Answer (score 0):

Php will not work without server.

You have to check it in localhost or live server.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a file on your computer, the link should begin with something like..

```
file:///path/to/location
```

Hope it works